# Unsuccessful build on gitlab runner

Tags: docker

Off recently we are facing the below issue while performing a CI/CD build from gitlab runner.

Below is the log snippet from `/var/log/syslog`.

```
pr 22 03:02:04 cirunner dockerd[1103]: time="2019-04-22T03:02:04.136857571Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.18/containers/runner-301e5f4d-project-786-concurrent-0-build-4 returned error: No such container: runner-301e5f4d-project-786-concurrent-0-build-4"



Apr 22 03:02:04 cirunner kernel: [1616845.656927] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1568]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch

Apr 22 03:02:04 cirunner kernel: [1616846.186616] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1568]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.383784] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1568]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner systemd-udevd[1187]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth0675b93: No such file or directory

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.385245] device veth8b64bcd entered promiscuous mode

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.385299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth8b64bcd: link is not ready

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner systemd-udevd[1188]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth8b64bcd: No such file or directory

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.788755] eth0: renamed from veth0675b93

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.804716] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth8b64bcd: link becomes ready

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.804739] docker0: port 3(veth8b64bcd) entered forwarding state

Apr 22 03:02:05 cirunner kernel: [1616846.804747] docker0: port 3(veth8b64bcd) entered forwarding state

Apr 22 03:02:20 cirunner kernel: [1616861.819201] docker0: port 3(veth8b64bcd) entered forwarding state



Apr 22 03:37:13 cirunner dockerd[1103]: time="2019-04-22T03:37:13.298195303Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET

/v1.18/containers/6f6b71442b5bbc70f980cd05272c8f05d514735f39e9b73b52a094a0e87db475/json returned error: No such container: 6f6b71442b5bbc70f980cd05272c8f05d514735f39e9b73b52a094a0e87db475"
```

Could you please help me out what exactly is the issue and how can to trouble shoot.

Let me know if you require additional details from my side.

Comment: Could you post the output of docker info?

Comment: From the log you provide, it looks like it is failing to find a container. Maybe you do not have that container or you do not have permission to access it. This is what one can guess from the above log.

Comment: Containers: 22
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 19
Images: 5242
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 3884
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive

Comment: Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-145-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.67 GiB
Name: cirunner
ID: RKSE:2MZQ:APMK:EYKG:5K6F:YQXO:SBFZ:CQPD:Q7WI:XMHN:NCE5:GZ7S
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

Comment: Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

Comment: @ ASR, The build issue happens intermittently, Few times the build passes